# Destructuring Response from a Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise, apollo-client, destructuring

I'm delving into promises and trying to achieve something like this. Where I have an async function.

```
async function myFunc(): Promise<{ data: any }> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve({ data: { item: "test" } })
    });
}
```

And I want to use it like this:

```
const {data} = myFunc();
```

Basically in the way useQuery would work in the apollo client for example.

Is there some way to achieve this? I'm guessing I'm way off track. I know you can use then or catch but I'm specifically looking to follow a pattern like useQuery does.

Comment: Since `myFunc();` returns a promise, you would need to `await` it to get the value which the promise resolves to. `await` can only be used in an async function though. Alternatively, you could use `.then()`. on your promise

Answer (score 3):

You'd do that either like this, in an `async` function:

```
const { data } = await myFunc();
```

or like this in a non-`async` function:

```
myFunc()
.then(({data}) => {
    // ...
})
// .catch here, probably
```

---

Just as as side note, there's no reason for the functino shown to be `async`. You only need `async` on a function if you use `await` within it and want it to automatically create a promise that's settled based on what's happening within the function. In your function, you don't use `await`, and you create the promise explicitly. (But that's probably just a placeholder...)

Comment: too fast... I was just writting that :)

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Maybe I'm asking the wrong question.  I've done it this way because of two main factors/assumptions:
1) the real implementation of myFunc calls a 3rd party module within it which is asynchronous so I assumed i needed to make myFunc async as a result.
2) myFunc will be called within a react component so making it "await" will cause problems.

Comment: @user1148920 - Either of those may well be a question of its own. :-) But FWIW: 1) If the 3rd party module's function returns a promise and you want to use `await` when calling it, your function will need to be `async`. Or you could use the promise's `.then`/`.catch`. If the 3rd party function is callback-style, probably best to use `new Promise` in a non-`async` function. 2) It's fine to use `async` and `await` in React if you handle it correctly (and if you aren't doing it where the functions' return value, which will be a promise, won't be used as a promise by whatever calls it). HTH! :-)